# UIWebView crash on ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

When i load a html on `UIWebView` in `ios8` app is crashing.
Second time when i open the page again it not crashing , it happens only in IOS 8.

On `ViewWillAppear` calling openLink

```
-(void)openLink{
NSString *pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathFile ];     
NSString *urlwithoutQueryString = [url absoluteString];
NSString * urlWithQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",urlwithoutQueryString, filePathAnchor];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWithQueryString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];

if ([webView request] != urlRequest){
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript:gotoInternalHref('0000');"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
}
```

Javascript Function

```
function gotoInternalHref(posIndex) {
LocationHash = "#" + posIndex;
positionindex = posIndex;

window.location.hash = LocationHash;
}
```

[image: Crash Screen Shots]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try debugging it with NSZombies enabled

Comment: @muffe2k It is enabled ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the problem. In my html i am using embed tag because of this it is crashing.

```
<embed width ="600" height ="400" src="01.jpg" href="01.mp4" type="video/mp4"  id="video-01"target ="myself" scale="1"/>
```

Changed to

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop width="600" height="400" poster="01.jpg" id="video-01" target="myself" scale="1">
    <source src="01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

it's working :) 
Thanks a lot.